# How to read different user inputs in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently checked javascript(nodejs) on HackerEarth. It had following code already written.

```
function main(input) {
//Enter your code here
```

}

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("utf-8");
var stdin_input = "";

process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
stdin_input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   main(stdin_input);
});
```

How do I read test cases with sample inputs such as

```
A)First line contains no. of test cases and size of array. 
Next T  lines contains array content.
- 3 4 
- 32 33 12 2
- 1 23 34 3
- 65 2 21 11

B)The first line contains the number of testcases, T. 
Next, T lines follow each containing a long string S.
 - 3
 - SUVKITSU
 - 651SUVOMN
 - SAHJ8HSAU6
```

So, all in all, my question is how to read input integers and strings and arrays in javascript(nodeJs) while doing competitive programming?

Answer (score 0):

Look at JavaScript's string methods, like `.split()` and `.substr()`.

Comment: .split() & .substr() will just split or extract particular length of string from main string. What I want is to read main string.